# How to graphically measure a relationship between variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

first of all my data:

```
dput(A22[1:10,])
structure(list(var1 = c("2.655086631421", "3.7212389963679",
"5.72853363351896", "9.08207789994776", "2.01681931037456", "8.98389684967697",
"9.44675268605351", "6.60797792486846", "6.29114043898881", "0.617862704675645"
), var2 = c("1552.74486613787", "-2569.05222968964", "444.924755180376",
"-30903.126560766", "5712.55164894465", "-15996.3316364127",
"-39466.7802848889", "-6396.48804278828", "662.572855848352",
"-542.783293142592"), var3 = c("12.0761815621956", "15.531955650981",
"24.3703946694194", "38.692940909924", "1.13425531130685", "37.6187150619221",
"48.2338786451232", "27.554822845155", "22.9179948054061", "7.56647601307255"
), var4 = c("0.136221893102778", "0.407167603423836", "-0.0696548130129049",
"-0.247664341619331", "0.69555080661964", "1.1462283572158",
"-2.40309621489187", "0.572739555245841", "0.374724406778655",
"-0.425267721556076"), gruppe = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1",
"1", "1", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I understand the data as the following: I have two different groups (group 0 und group 1). In each group var1, var2, var3, var4 are measured.

My tasks are:

```
(a)Visualize the distribution of var1. Do you recognize group-specific differences?
(b)Graphically analyze the relationship between the following variables:
   (i)var1 and var3 
   (ii)var1 and var2 
   (iii)var1 and var4
(c)Calculate an introductory measure to measure the relationship.
```

My main problem is:
I don't know how to extract (for example in (a)) var1 from my data and how to somehow condition it on the group and visualize it.

I am happy about help.

Best regards & nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with `ggplot2`, I'll answer with ggplot2 in mind. The data you've provided is in a so called 'wide format', as opposite to 'long format'. ggplot2 works better with 'long format' data, so the first step is to transform the data with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. Then, you can make facetted kernel density plots to show the distribution of the different variables in different facets and colour by group.

```r
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(A22, cols = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"))
# or: df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(A22, !gruppe)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(as.numeric(value), fill = as.factor(gruppe))) +
  geom_density(alpha  = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your quick help! Could you explain, what you did in your first step ? I never heard about "wide format" or "long format". And what exactly does the command "facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")"?. Once again, many thanks.!

Comment: The `pivot_longer()` function transforms from wide data to long data. Long data has one observation per row, whereas wide data has some column structure to indicate parallel observations, but has multiple observations per row. The `facet_wrap()` command puts every `var*` in its own panel, with free x and y axes.

Comment: Understood. Perfect. Thank you. :)